# Getting HTTP Error 500.30 - PhysicalFileProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to use a Path outside from wwwroot for some files which can only reached by authorized user and found the PhysicalFileProvider Method.

My Startup looks like:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();


        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Files")),
            RequestPath = "/Files"
        });
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

nothing special here i think and works on my local machine.
After Upload this to the hosting server (Hoster: smarterasp.net) i get HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure. If i comment out the new StaticFileOptions it works, of course the Folder isn´t reachable.

Do i have anything more to do when using the PhysicalFileProvider?

Using .Net Core 3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced the error of you,and the error is caused by the Path cannot be found.I soveld it by adding the static file folder into the publish folder.

This is my partial code of my startup.cs:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                    Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Files")),
                RequestPath = "/Files"
            });
```

And this is my partial code of view:

```
<img src="~/Files/banner1.svg" alt="ASP.NET" class="img-responsive" />
```

The publish folder contains the content required for publishing,I add the Files Folder  into publish folder.And then it works.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Many many thank for your answer. It can be such simple. Only thing i have is that i dont have a publish folder. I added the Files Folder in my root an had to add  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Files\" />
    </ItemGroup> in the project file. Thank you very much!

Comment: The "Files" Folder is still direct reachable by url/files/{filename}.{extension}, any Ideas how to fix this? That was the only reason to add this folder...